# DB2 query with slash in table name

Tags: db2

please I have table name **SAPPRD./CS1/TB2_SOPBV** and I can´t do this query:

```
transfer ownership of table SAPPRD./CS1/TB2_SOPBV TO USER SAPQAS preserve privileges;
```

I am getting error:

> DB21034E The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was
>   not a valid Command Line Processor command. During SQL processing it
>   returned: SQL0104N An unexpected token "/CS1/" was found following
>   "hip of table SAPFIP.". Expected tokens may include: "".
>   SQLSTATE=42601

So I tried to do escaping, I edited query to:

```
transfer ownership of table SAPPRD.\"/CS1/TB2_SOPBV" TO USER SAPQAS preserve privileges
```

But It will not escape, I am still getting error:

> DB21034E The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was
>   not a valid Command Line Processor command. During SQL processing it
>   returned: SQL0007N The statement was not processed because a character
>   that is not supported in SQL statements was included in the SQL
>   statement. Invalid character: "\". Text preceding the invalid
>   character: "hip of table SAPPRD.". SQLSTATE=42601

Is possible to do escaping here and proceed with this query?

Thank you!

Comment: By the way, very bad naming strategy for tables.

Comment: @AngocA Yes, but It's SAP naming strategy an I must respect that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved!

```
transfer ownership of table SAPPRD."/CS1/TB2_SOPBV" TO USER SAPQAS preserve privileges
```